# Large x behaviour of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, asymptotics

I have the following implicit equation:

$$x=\frac{4\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}+\sqrt{3y^2-y}}{3}$$

I am interested in it's behaviour for large x, surely as x increases, y increases hence $y^2$ in the square root dominates and we end up with $x=y/\sqrt{3}$.

I have plotted y against x (blue plot9 as well as $y=\sqrt{3}$ (green curve)however, they don't seem to converge, is there anything wrong with my logic?

[image: Plot of the function and line]

Comment: Is it better for you ?

Comment: Yes, it approximates the solution almost perfectly, except that when I solve the quadratic, my constant term is 11/6 instead of 3/2.

Comment: I double checked and my result looks to be correct.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I forgot a factor of two when Taylor expanding.

Comment: Good to know ! In fact, do we care about the constant term when we go to infinity ? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider $$x=\frac{4\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}+\sqrt{3y^2-y}}{3}$$ and use a Taylor series for infinitely large values of $y$, you should get
$$x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{2 \sqrt{2} }{3}\sqrt{y}-\frac{1}{6
   \sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{72 \sqrt{3}
   y}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^{3/2}}\right)$$ and this matches the results to very high accuracy as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 y & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 10 & 8.6578861 & 8.6578997 \\
 20 & 15.666746 & 15.666750 \\
 30 & 22.387992 & 22.387994 \\
 40 & 28.960432 & 28.960433 \\
 50 & 35.437794 & 35.437795 \\
 60 & 41.847625 & 41.847625 \\
 70 & 48.206285 & 48.206286 \\
 80 & 54.524436 & 54.524437 \\
 90 & 60.809482 & 60.809482 \\
 100 & 67.066812 & 67.066812
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, ignoring the terms with negative powers of $y$, you can solve the quadratic and get $$y=\sqrt{3}\, x-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{20+24 \sqrt{3}\, x}+\frac{3}{2}$$ which, expanded again, would give $$y=\sqrt{3} x-\frac{2 \sqrt{2} }{\sqrt[4]{3}}\sqrt{x}+\frac{3}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}\right)$$

For a sanity check, I replaced in the initial rhs $y$ by this last expression in $x$ and developed it as a Taylor series for infinitely large values of $x$. The obtained result is $$x+\frac{5}{9 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}}\frac 1 {\sqrt x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$